# It can not find my variable in my view in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, variables

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\News;
use App\User;
use App\Event;

public function index()
    {
        $datanews['newss'] = News::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $dataevent['events'] = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $user['users'] = User::all();
        return view('user/aktuelles.index',$datanews, $dataevent,$user);
    }
```

this is a part of my controller, i can show news and events in my view but everytime it says it can not find the variable user?

i dont know why because i dont know why it shows me the other variables but not the user variable???

in my view i can see the other variables like this:

```
@foreach ($newss as $news)
{{$news->newstitel}}
@endforeach
```

but i want to show user like this:

```
{{$user[1]->avatar}}
```

i tried everything so i tried so look my controller like this:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->get();
```

or get the variable via compact
and i tried exactly the same so like this

```
$user['users'] = User::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

and a foreach in my view but it can not found the variable user??

i dont know why

this is the error

```
Undefined variable: users
```

Comment: try to initialize `$user = [];` at the top of the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return view('user.aktuelles.index', compact('datanews', 'dataevent', 'user');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the helper `view()` handles the 4th parameter you are passing. According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views) you can pass data like this:

```
return view('user/aktuelles.index',[
    'datanews' => $datanews,
    'dataevent' => $dataevent,
    'user' => $user,
]);
```

or

```
return view('user/aktuelles.index')->with([
    'datanews' => $datanews,
    'dataevent' => $dataevent,
    'user' => $user,
]);
```

Maybe give this way a try.

**Edit:**
The `view()` helper accepts 3 Parameters: $view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [] so the 4th parameter you are trying to pass is not even working. You have to pass your data as second parameter or with the chained function `with(array $data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return value in view like below method:

Change this line

```
$user['users'] = User::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

To

```
$user = User::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
return view('user/aktuelles.index', ['datanews' => $datanews,'dataevent'=> $dataevent,'users'=>$user]);
```

Now, You will get result inside your view using 'users'.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing variables to view correctly use **with** or **compact** to pass variables to view.
i prefer compact as it is simple and easier.

Passing data to view using **compact**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\News;
use App\User;
use App\Event;

public function index()
    {
        $datanews  = News::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $dataevent = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $user      = User::all();
        return view('user.aktuelles.index',compact('datanews', 'dataevent','user'));
    }
```

Passing variables to view using **with**:

```
 public function index()
        {
            $datanews  = News::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
            $dataevent = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
            $user      = User::all();
            return view('user.aktuelles.index)->with(['datanews' => $datanews,'dataevent'=> $dataevent,'users'=>$user]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\News;
use App\User;
use App\Event;

public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = News::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    $data['events'] = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    $data['users'] = User::all();
    return view('user/aktuelles.index', $data);
}
```